# Facebook Feed Plugin adaptative height

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-iframe

I have embed the **Facebook Plugin** on the "news section" of a web-page, I'm making.
The news section has **two columns**. The **left column** will display the 5 latest posts and the **right column** will show the Facebook feed.

As you can imagine, the left column's height will depend on the content of the posts.
What i would like to do, is to make the right column's **height** (Facebook Feed) adapt to the **right's column height** (make it 100% of parent's height).

I have tried lots of different things, like height 100%, position absolute, even jquery,..., but nothing seems to work. It feels like the height of the iframe is hard-coded.
The only way i found to change the height is through the `data-height=""` attribute, but i can't make that adapt the left column's height.

There is an option for **adaptive-width**, but none for **adaptive height**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such option - the only supported parameters are those listed in the [Page Plugin documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) - there is indeed an adaptive width option but not so for height